# Updating field based on another field in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap

I need to update a field based on another layers field. I could do this in arcmap manually by joining the two layers together and then using field calculator. Is there a way I can do it with a script? I.e just enter the field as an input and run it and it will calculate the field I need.

I was thinking along the lines of

```
inputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

searchcursor, updatecursor?
```

all I want is the average of a field in one layer to be entered into one row/column in another.

I should also add I want this as a script so it automatically creates a new field in the polyline and puts the average of the other layers field in it.

Comment: "all I want is the average of a field in one layer to be entered into one row/column in another" -- this statement is confusing, can you elaborate? Which row in the "other" table should the "average of a field in one layer" be entered? The first? Does the row already exist?

Comment: sorry. I have a field of values in a layer (94) of them. I want the average of these values (e.g sum/94) to be inputted into a field with a polyline. I could do this manually by joining the layers, then using field calculator to AVG/values

Comment: Okay, lets say layer A is the layer with the 94 rows you want the average of field X. Layer B is what? A polyline layer with just one feature? Or are there many features? What is the relationship between A and B (one to one, many to one, etc)?

Comment: yes, its a polylinez with just one feature. Layer A is a multipoint feature of the polyline, that is, the polyline converted to many points.

Comment: And they are related by a common ID I assume? Do you want the script to be generic enough that it can work even if Layer B has more than one feature? Sorry for the 20 questions.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the details of the question correctly (described in the comments), I think you should be able to do all of this in two steps using built-in geoprocessing tools, which you can of course also script in Python:

1. Use [Summary Statistics (Analysis)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000.htm), to create a table with the
   mean value of field X in layer A. Specify the Case field to be the ID field that relates layer A to layer B.
2. Use [Join Field (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000065000000), to permanently join the
   mean value field from the result of step 1 to layer B.

Try it out interactively in ArcToolbox first, then in the Results window, right-click the results for each of the two steps and click "Copy As Python snippet", and paste them into a new Python script. Tweak as needed (read in parameters and assign to variables, use variables in the tool arguments instead of hard-coding them, etc).

Here is an example workflow, which hopefully you will find can be applied to many other problems.

---

**Data description:**
I have a point feature class named `atlantic_hurricanes_2000` (from the ArcObjects SDK sample data) that has many points recording windspeed, pressure, etc., along the path of each hurricane from the 2000 hurricane season:
[image]
[image]

I created a polyline feature class from it for the purposes of demonstration (each line is a separate hurricane track). The only meaningful attribute on the polyline layer, `EVENTID` is the name of the hurricane which will serve as an ID field that relates back to the point feature class:
[image]
[image]

**Problem statement:** The point feature class has a `WINDSPEED` field recording the wind speed at each point of a given hurricane track. I want to take the mean `WINDSPEED` value of all the points for each track in the point feature class and assign it to each polyline feature by adding a field.

**Solution:**

1. I used Summary Statistics as follows:
   [image]

   Which produced this table:
   [image]
2. I then used Join Field as follows:
   [image]

**Final result:**
[image]

**Python snippet output:**

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis("C:/GISData/test.gdb/atlantic_hurricanes_2000","C:/GISData/test.gdb/atlantic_hurricanes_2000_average_windspeed","WINDSPEED MEAN","EVENTID")
arcpy.JoinField_management("C:/GISData/test.gdb/atlantic_hurricanes_2000_lines","EVENTID","C:/GISData/test.gdb/atlantic_hurricanes_2000_average_windspeed","EVENTID","MEAN_WINDSPEED")
```

Comment: thanks thats great. i turned the whole thing including my other processes into a model but when i export it as a python script and run it i get an error gp is not defined?

Comment: Please edit your original question to include the script and error message.

Comment: Or better yet, ask a new question since I anticipate the problem being something specific to the "ModelBuilder to Python" step.